# How to print \" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

In ruby, quotation marks can be printed in a string if it is immediately preceded with a backslash: `print " \" "`.

But how do i print `\"` in ruby without the backslash disappearing due to the presence of the quotation mark immediately before it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Escape the backslash then escape the quote: `print "\\\""`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use single quote (`'`) instead of double quote (`"`) to prevent interpretation of escape sequence:

```
irb(main):001:0> print '\"'
\"=> nil
```

or `%q{...}` in case there are many `'`s in the string:

```
irb(main):002:0> print %q{\"}
\"=> nil
```